# Is there any way to detect window layover on a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am working on a `web-app` which should do some function when the user moves away from that tab.
I managed to detect tab switching, and also browser switching through

```
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => this.dothis())
```

But still i can't detect if a user opens `system-settings` like preferences or settings, or any other built-in system tool. Is there a way to detect those?

Comment: No. You cannot detect what program the user has in focus on the client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event does what you need. It triggers when the active tab loses focus to another tab, another window or another application.

If needed, you can combine it with the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event, which is triggered when the opposite happens (a non-focused tab gains focus).

```
window.addEventListener('blur', () => /* ... */ );

window.addEventListener('focus', () => /* ... */ );
```